# "Entity '@p...' cannot be found" error message

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Every time I enter a variation of:

> /effect @p...

I receive an error message "Entity '@p...' cannot be found"

[image: Error Message]

The image is just one example. I've tried it without commas. With x=, y=, z= in front of the coordinates. I've mixed and matched everything until I feel like I've tried everything, but obviously I'm missing something.

How did I misbrain this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have spaces in a selector. Command arguments are separated by spaces, so it assumes that, for example, "@p[454," is the entity to target and that "201," is the effect to apply.

As of 1.11, you must include the key names for coordinates ("x=", "y=", "z=").

```
/effect @p[x=454,y=201,z=782,r=3] minecraft:speed
```

Comment: Well now I feel foolish. It's been too long since I've worked with commands. Thanks!